# SQL Server Stored Procedure for updating rows from Table 1 based on rows from Table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

**Table 1**

```
Code Value
AAA  100
BBB  200
CCC  300
DDD  400
```

**Table 2**

```
Code NewCode
AAA  ALPHA
BBB  BETA
DDD  DELTA
```

How do you create a stored procedure that will update all the Code in Table 1 so to the NewCode they should have based on Table 2? So that the end result will be something like this:

```
Code   Value
ALPHA  100
BETA   200
CCC    300
DELTA  400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Code=Table2.Newcode
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.Code=Table2.Code
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is procedure creation:

```
USE [myDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
(
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE TABLE1-----------THAT IS THE QUERY.
        SET TABLE1.Code = TABLE2.NewCode
    WHERE TABLE1.Code = TABLE2.Code
END
```